# How do I make a suggested edit?

Tags: support

As someone who went from 500 rep to 3k rep in a couple of month's, I've come to miss some of the "privileges" of having low rep.

In the same way that moderators might want to simply "vote close" rather than insta-close a question. I want to simply make a suggestion for an edit rather than an insta-edit. I want my edits to be approved by other people, especially the persons question/answer I am editing. Otherwise it feels as if I am stepping on other people's toes.

Before I had instant edit privilege, I saw "oh this.. certainly need a little puff to look better / get the point across seamlessly". And knowing that other people would only say "yes" if it was correct gave me the feeling that "if your edit is crap, then it won't go through". Like a safe edit.

Nowadays I barely edit (only did some edits for the hat thingy), and the only edits I do is text to mathjax edits so it looks "correct" / "serious" / has the quality of being on EE.SE.

---

With that said, **is there any way to make suggested edits to questions / answers as someone with +3k rep**? Or should I make 3x 500 bounties to drop my rep to below 2k? Because I really miss that feature. 

But then.. if I got below 2k rep, then I will miss the vote to close option, because some questions really... need that vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see a post that could be improved, there are two possibilities:

- I just want to make minor grammatical/aesthetic improvements, or change a few sentences to make the post clearer, and this doesn't change the substance of the post itself: I go on with an edit.
- I feel there is something wrong, or that there is a missing piece of information in the post. This would change the intent of the post: I make a comment to suggest the improvement to the poster. I later check if the post has been edited and eventually delete my comment if it became obsolete.

But I am pretty sure the edits you are talking about fall into the first category. In that case, please proceed with the edit. The poster gets notified and will have the opportunity to roll back anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats on reaching 3k.

Don't worry about stepping on people's toes. They always have the option of rolling back your edits completely. The other thing is that every edit pushes the post to the top of the active list, and everyone gets to review it.

You've done well enough, you know the rules. You don't need the close supervision of the edit review queue any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing when it comes to editing is making sure the question is readable (good grammar and punctuation) so it looks presentable. Get rid of all the text speech. Changing equations is another way to make questions look good. Sometimes there are formatting errors.

The next thing that may be a little hard to do is [eliminate first person speech](https://www.acs.edu.au/info/environment/bio-science/technical-documentation.aspx) (if its a question that is worthy of making it look professional). In doing this is helps the editor be a better technical writer. In academic and technical settings first person speech (pronouns) are harder to read and not necessary.

I sometimes rewrite the answer and provide a specific question to make it more readable.

If the OP objects to this, they are more then welcome to edit their own post. 
More often than not, it's easier to edit the post than it is to let them edit it so edit away.

Comment: Why does the link point to ACS Distance Education? (I'm assuming this was a copy-paste error)

Comment: No the link is down